# Migration from MySQL 8.0.16 to MySQL 5.5 - wrong accents and special characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, database-migration, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.5

Good morning,
I need to migrate a MySQL 8.0.16 database into a MySQL 5.5 instance.

all worked well, but all the words with accents (e.g. `Giacenza-Disponibilità`) were ported in the new database like the wrong charset was used (`Giacenza-Disponibilit├á`).

The original DB charset settings were:

```
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

While the destination database couldn't be set to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` as that collation, I read, is not available for MySQL < 5.6.
I tried setting many different utf8 and utf8mb4 charsets, like `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, but the resulting database still contains broken records, like in the example before. If i insert any new record, like perché, it will be stored and shown correctly.

could anyone please suggest me a way to migrate the database without encountering those issues?

Comment: Why are you going backwards to a less optimized version ? In MySQL < 5.6, you will need to use `utf8_general_ci` as Collation, and `utf8` as Charset

Comment: it's because I need to install the mroonga library. I tried using those sets, but the result is still broken (validitÃƒÂ instead of validità).

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I exported the whole database into a .sql script, and transformed the file encoding to ANSI with n++, now the migration works correctly.

Comment: ciao oramai penso abbia risolto brillantemente in questo modo ma io avrei creato prima l'istanza (il db vuoto) in utf8_unicode_ci e poi avrei reimportato il db precedente

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, you are using one of these `CHARACTER SETs`: cp850, cp852, keybcs2, correct?  They transform the UTF-8 encoding (hex `c3a0`) for `à` to `├á`.

See "Mojibake" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for a list of the things that are problably not set correctly:

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded. (This does not seem to be the problem.)
- The *connection* when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4. This is probably the cause.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`). (Not the problem)
- HTML should start with .